# Added custom woocommerce product page hook

Tags: wordpress

I inserted this code snippet in the functions.php of my child theme, to create the woocommerce single product page in the hook woocommerce_after_single_variation of the custom icons in line centered on the text, without using css, everything works, but I ask you much more experienced if that's okay, or could you do better? thank you so much ( sorry my poor english, i use translate :)

```
/**
 * added 3 icons in line to the single product page
 */

 add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_variation', 'icone_rassicurazione_cliente');
 function icone_rassicurazione_cliente() { 
    echo '<i class="fas fa-undo" style="font-size:40px; text-align:center; border-radius:20px margin-left: 0 auto; margin-right: 5%;">
             <p style="text-align: center;">
               <h6>reso  gratuito<br>antro 90 gg</h6></i>' ;

    echo '<i class="fas fa-phone-volume" style="font-size:40px; text-align:center; border-radius:20px margin-left: 5%; margin-right:5%;">
             <p style="text-align: center;">
               <h6>assistenza anche<br>tramite whatsapp</h6></i>' ;

    echo '<i class="fab fa-cc-paypal" style="font-size:40px; text-align:center; border-radius:20px margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 0 auto;">
             <p style="text-align: center;">
               <h6>pagameni certificati<br>Paypal, carta di</h6></i>' ;

}
```